# How to keep the bottom navigation bar visible in detail pages in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I was trying to build a bottom navigation bar in the initial page of an App, I added several tabs in this bottom bar and users should be able to tap on one of them to get to different tabs. But the bar is only to navigate to other pages. In one of these pages, I added a `card` and users should tap on them to detail pages. HOWEVER, when it's in the detail page, the navigation bar disappeared. I am wondering how to keep my navigation bar always visible in the app.

The code below is about how i establish the bottom bar in my home page,

```
......

  int currentTab = 0; // to keep track of active tab index
  final List<Widget> screens = [
    recommend(),
    optional(),
    backtest(),
    machine(),
  ]; // to store tab views

  Widget currentScreen = recommend(); // initial pages

  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket(); 

......

  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0.2,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 10,
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = recommend();
                        currentTab = 0;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.format_line_spacing,
                        color: currentTab == 0 ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.grey,),
                      Text(
                        '',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: currentTab == 0 ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.grey, ),)
                    ],),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = optional();
                        currentTab = 1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                      Icon(
                        Icons.offline_pin,
                        color: currentTab == 1 ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.grey,),
                      Text(
                        '',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: currentTab == 1 ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.grey, ),)
                    ],),
                  ),
                ],
              ),

              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = backtest();
                        currentTab = 2;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.replay,
                          color: currentTab == 2 ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.grey,),
                        Text(
                          '',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 2 ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.grey, ),)
                      ],),
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        currentScreen = machine();
                        currentTab = 3;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Icon(
                          Icons.android,
                          color: currentTab == 3 ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.grey,),
                        Text(
                          '',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: currentTab == 3 ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.grey, ),)
                      ],),
                  ),
                ],
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

The code below is how I navigate to the detail page,

```
 return Container(
      child: Card(
        child: new InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => stockDetail()));
          },
......
```

I'm looking for an approach to solve the problem based on my existed code, but i would appreciate it if there are any other efficient way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this plugin [Presistant_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar).Based on question you need the bottomnav bar in every pages.you can disable the bottomnav in specific screen checkout above link

it very good plugin in my opinion.checkout navgation style in this link.you can change the desgin of bottomnavbar  navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style9, just change the style9 to whatever number provided by plugin. i believe 15 of them available

You can use your custom icon instead of default icon, also instead of this CupertinoColors.systemPurple you can also use Colors.red kind of this Let me know if it works

```
PersistentTabController _controller =PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);

//Screens for each nav items.
  List<Widget> _NavScreens() {
    return [
      recommend(),
      optional(),
      backtest(),
      machine(),
      
    ];
  }


  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
       icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: ("Recommend"),
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
        title: ("Optional"),
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
        inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin),
        title: ("Backtest"),
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.systemRed,
        inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.local_activity),
        title: ("Machine"),
        activeColor: CupertinoColors.systemIndigo,
        inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),

    ];
  }
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: PersistentTabView(
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _NavScreens(),
        items: _navBarsItems(),
        confineInSafeArea: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
        decoration: NavBarDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
        navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style9,
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've used this package in my project, but I encountered an error said `A PersistentTabController was used after being disposed.` when I was trying to change the exact style. How it comes with the problem?

Comment: can you update the question with changed code..? @LeYoungChen

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem. From what I understand from your query is that the different pages are being called on different tabs (in bottom navigation bar) but the app bar/the bottom navigation bar itself is not visible.

I would suggest you to create another dart file. Lets say it `blank.dart` for convenience. In this blank.dart you write your code for the bottom navigation bar (which you have already written) and call all the different pages in this blank.dart
So basically, the navigation bar will be common to all the other pages that will be called inside this blank.dart
you can understand it as blank.dart being the parent and all other different tabs being its child, so the parent can navigate to its child widgets.

you can have a look at my GitHub for the similar solution at lib/screens/blank.dart : http://github.com/samflab/fitility

Answer (score 0):

Hi u can solve this by adding BottomNavigationBar in main.dart and then according to the currentIndex of BottomNavigationBaritem you can change the screen in scaffold(body:anyScreenAccordingToindex).for example if currentIndex==2 then body:secondPage()